# Is CO + O ==> CO2 a possibility for propelling rockets off Mars?

Tags: mars, crewed-spaceflight, fuel, perseverance, oxygen

Perseverance, the Mars rover, includes an experiment called [MOXIE](https://mars.nasa.gov/news/8926/nasas-perseverance-mars-rover-extracts-first-oxygen-from-red-planet/). This is a technology demonstration to show that Mars' atmospheric carbon dioxide can be broken into carbon monoxide and oxygen.  Future missions would use a much scaled up version of MOXIE to generate oxygen for life support and particularly for rocket propulsion for the return trip.  The referenced article talks about taking a 1 tonne oxygen generator and 7 tonnes of rocket fuel (RP1?) to Mars.

My question is why not just take the 1 tonne generator and accumulate and store both the carbon monoxide and the oxygen locally and burn them together to propel the rocket.  I assume there is a big disadvantage compared with more conventional fuels, but does this really outweigh having to convey 7 tonnes of rocket fuel to Mars?

Comment: Moxie is neat, but they could split water into H2 and O2,  then react 4H2 + CO2 ==> CH4 + 2H2O (Sabatier process).  Better for SpaceX Starship.

Comment: @Robert DiGiovanni Yes, you'd have to find the water first, but then you would have methane and oxygen for propulsion.